# How can I load a dump thru Powerdbg's "New-DbgSession" command?

Tags: powershell, windbg, crash-dumps, powershell-4.0

I am trying to use the [Powerdbg module](https://powerdbg.codeplex.com/) to analyse a kernel dump. I have managed to successfully install the module. But I am unable to start a new session.

`New-DbgSession -dump F:\Downloads\021715-61105-01.dmp`

But it opens a blank command prompt titled "CDB.exe" and does nothing. I have Windbg installed on my machine. and the `debuggerroot' variable is rightly pointed to its path. What could I be doing wrong?

The codeplex Powerdbg discussion page isn't active.

Comment: Never used this but I think you are missing quotes around the path so try this: `New-DbgSession -dump 'F:\Downloads\021715-61105-01.dmp'`

Comment: @EdChum Nope, tried that too.

Comment: Presumably it invokes (or tries to invoke) CDB with a particular set of arguments. Use Task Manager or Process Explorer, right-click on the column set and include the command line. This should provide a clue as to what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have been intending to try this so i downloaded the latest package and tested it result is as follows see if you can follow through it

i created a bat file which sets the DebuggingTools Environment variable to windows 8.0 debugger installation (xp virtual machine) 
in the bat file i invoke powershell with Import-module 
when i get a ps command prompt i start a new verbose dbgSession with a dumpfile test.dmp located at c:\

```
:dir /b
Install_PowerDbg.bat
PowerDbg.psm1
PowerDbgConsole.ps1
PowerDbg_6.10.10.22.zip
runpdbg.bat

:type runpdbg.bat
set DebuggingTools=c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86
c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -noexit -comma
nd "Import-Module" .\powerdbg.psm1
:runpdbg.bat

:set DebuggingTools=c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86

:c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -noexit -comm
and "Import-Module" .\powerdbg.psm1
WARNING: Some imported command names include unapproved verbs which might make
them less discoverable.  Use the Verbose parameter for more detail or type
Get-Verb to see the list of approved verbs.
WARNING: Some imported command names contain one or more of the following
restricted characters: # , ( ) {{ }} [ ] & - / \ $ ^ ; : " ' < > | ? @ ` * % +
= ~
PS C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\PowerDbg_6.10.10.22> New-DbgSession -
verbose -dump C:\test.dmp
VERBOSE: Using debugging tools from c:\Program Files\Windows
Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86
VERBOSE: c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\CDB.exe -z C:\test.dmp
VERBOSE:

Verb                    :
Arguments               : -z C:\test.dmp
CreateNoWindow          : False
EnvironmentVariables    : {pathext, homepath, symbol_path, clientname...}
RedirectStandardInput   : True
RedirectStandardOutput  : True
RedirectStandardError   : True
StandardErrorEncoding   :
StandardOutputEncoding  :
UseShellExecute         : False
Verbs                   : {Enable/Disable Digital Signature Icons, open, Open
i
                          n PPEE (puppy), Open with CFF Explorer...}
UserName                :
Password                :
Domain                  :
LoadUserProfile         : False
FileName                : c:\Program Files\Windows
Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\CDB.e
                          xe
WorkingDirectory        : C:\Documents and
Settings\Admin\Desktop\PowerDbg_6.10
                          .10.22
ErrorDialog             : False
ErrorDialogParentHandle : 0
WindowStyle             : Normal



VERBOSE: RX (discard)
VERBOSE: TX: .echo PowerDbg connected
VERBOSE: RX: PowerDbg connected
VERBOSE: RX: 0:000> PowerDbg_Complete_184742.640
VERBOSE: RX Complete
VERBOSE: RX (discard) 0:000>
VERBOSE: TX: .printf "%d\n", @$ptrsize
VERBOSE: RX: 4
VERBOSE: RX: 0:000> PowerDbg_Complete_184742.656
VERBOSE: RX Complete
VERBOSE: Connected to 32 bit process/dump
PS C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\PowerDbg_6.10.10.22>
```

this command also seems to start a session correctly  (you may need to add debugger path explicitly in $searchpath in powerdbg.psm1 line arount 440 in function Get-DbgToolsLocation()

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noexit -File PowerDbgConsole.ps1 -verbose -dump c:\test.dmp
```

Comment: I wrongly assumed that I was supposed to run the commands on the newly-opened non-responsive command prompt. When I ran the command with the '-verbose` switch I realized that the Powershell session was already connected to the debugger. Thank you for pointing out.